# Rails ActiveRecord where datetime not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, datetime, activerecord, scoping

I have a Model which has_one Schedule (from:datetime, from_a:datetime, to:datetime). I want to retrieve all models that have a schedule that fits the datetime the query is run.

For example, I have the model **m** that has a schedule of **from:  Sun, 15 Oct 2018 19:00:00 UTC +00:00**, **from_a:  Sun, 14 Oct 2018 19:20:00 UTC +00:00** and **to: Sun, 14 Oct 2018 20:00:00 UTC +00:00**. If the current time is *Sun, 14 Oct 2018 19:14:00 UTC +00:00* then and I search with only *from* then I would get m, but if the current time is *Sun, 14 Oct 2018 20:01:00 UTC +00:00* and I search with only *from* I would get nothing.

Here is the code that I've tried:

```
scope :s, ->(time, type) { unscoped.joins(:schedule).where("\"schedule.#{type.to_s}\" < ? AND \"schedule.to\" > ?", time, time) }
```

and when I call the scope would be `Model.s(DateTime.now, :from)`. The thing is that this code is not working as intended as it doesn't give me the correct result, nor the result that I expect.

**UPDATE**
This is the generated query for `Model.s(DateTime.now, :from)`

```
SELECT "models".* FROM "models" INNER JOIN "schedules" ON "schedules"."model_id" = "models"."id" WHERE ("schedules.from" < '2018-10-15 19:59:33.737073' AND "schedules.to" > '2018-10-15 19:59:33.737073')
```

Comment: Any help wold be appreciated, if i missed something please tell me. I know it's a bit messy, but i have an hard time trying to explain myself... so i am sorry for any mistakes i've made...

Comment: Please add the generated query (from your console) to your question (using the edit link below the tags). Also, you comment doesn't add to the question. Perhaps delete it?

Comment: it is plural, i deleted the s for some strange reasons, regarding single quotes it gives me an error if i don't put them @muistooshort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems, the first of which hides the others:

1. Single quotes are used for string literals in SQL so `'schedule.from'` and `'schedule.to'` are just strings in SQL, not references to columns in the `schedule` table.
2. `schedule` should be `schedules` since Rails likes to use plurals for table names.
3. `to` and `from` are [keywords](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html) in SQL and PostgreSQL (which you appear to be using) so they have to be (double) quoted when you use them as column names.

The first is fixed by removing the stray single quotes. The second by using a plural table name. The third by double quoting the offending identifiers. The result would be something like:

```
unscoped.joins(:schedule).where(%Q(schedules."#{type.to_s}" < ? and schedules."to" > ?), time, time)
```

or perhaps:

```
unscoped.joins(:schedule).where(%Q(schedules."#{type.to_s}" < :time and schedules."to" > :time), time: time)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I did all the things that you wrote and it still return an empty array...

Comment: @Anonymus I wish I could forget about timezones, they're evil :)